# set global Function/variables with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, global, react-hooks

I'm trying to get several infomartions that I want to display in a dashboard so I wrote a function to make things more modular and i  make a global function,
but I have an error that stops the execution.

Here the error

```
TypeError: _function__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__ is not a function
```

here the declaration on my function in a file called function.js

```
export const getData=(url,callBack) =>{

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }
    })
    .then(jsonResponse => {
      callBack(jsonResponse);
      return jsonResponse;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
```

Here the import and use

```
import * as getData from  "../function"



const App = () => {
  const URL="http://...";

  const [count, setCount]=useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
   getData(URL,setCount);

  });
```

I want to call this function in every screen

Comment: Can you please show an example of where you're calling this?

Comment: @Curt I edited my post, i added the sample of my App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in import statement.

Change the import statement to:

```
import {getData} from  "../function"
```

Answer (score 2):

Validate relative path imports  and change to

```
  import *  as api from  "../function".
```

using example

```
  api.getData(URL,setCount);
```